# Django - NoReverseMatch at /Profile/user

Tags: python, django, slug

My problem is I am getting a NoReverseMatch error after clicking one of the links on my homepage. The problem points to a text file which I refuse to delete.

Here's the code that's causing the problems

```
<a href="{% url 'edit_Profile' slug=Profile.slug %}">Edit me!</>
```

Heres my code

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from webapp.models import Profile
from webapp.forms import ProfileForm

def index(request):
    Profiles = Profile.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {
    'Profiles': Profiles,
})

def Profile_detail(request, slug):

    Profiles = Profile.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'Profiles/Profile_detail.html', {
    'Profile': Profile,
})



def edit_Profile(request, slug):

    Profile = Profile.objects.get(slug=slug)
    form_class = ProfileForm

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = form_class(data=request.POST, instance=Profile)
        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()
            return redirect('Profile_detail', slug=Profile.slug)

    else:
        form = form_class(instance=Profile)

    # and render the template
    return render(request, 'Profiles/edit_Profile.html', {
        'Profile': Profile,
        'form': form,
    })
```

url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from webapp import views


from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from webapp import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='home'),
    url(r'^about/$',
        TemplateView.as_view(template_name='about.html'), name='about'),
    url(r'^contact/$',
        TemplateView.as_view(template_name='contact.html'), name='contact'),
    url(r'^Profiles/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.Profile_detail, 
        name='Profile_detail'),
    url(r'^things/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/edit/$', 
        views.edit_Profile,
        name='edit_Profile'),
]
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

from webapp.models import Profile

class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('name', 'description',)
```

profile_detail.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
     {{ Profile.name }} - {{ block.super }}
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ Profile.name }}</h1>
    <p>{{ Profile.description }}</p>
    <a href="{% url 'edit_Profile' slug=Profile.slug %}">Edit me!</>
    {% endblock content %}
```

Comment: I'm not see your url `edit_Profile` is configured in the `urlpatterns`, you missed `url(r'^profile/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/edit/$', views.edit_Profile, name='edit_Profile'),`

Comment: Good eye! but unfortunately the template problem still remains.

Answer (score 0):

```
url(r'^Profiles/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.Profile_detail, 
        name='Profile_detail')
```

The name is `Profile_detail` other than `edit_Profile` in your template.

For example with a named url, you should do in `url.py`:

```
(r'^about_me/', about_me_view, name='about_me')
```

In the template:

```
<a href={% url 'about_me' %}>about me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter in the url templatetag is matched against names in urls.py, not against view functions's names.
The other thing is you have no entry pointing to the edit_Profile function.

To make this work you need to add an urlpattern pointing to the function in urls.py with the name 'edit_Profile', for example:

```
url(r'^Profiles/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/edit$', views.edit_Profile, 
    name='edit_Profile')
```

Recommended reading: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/

Comment: Could you elaborate more about the template?

Comment: If you mean the link <a href="{% url 'edit_Profile' slug=Profile.slug %}">Edit me!</> it should work fine if there's no other problems and if you fix the closing tag (replace </> with </a>). The error you mentioned was caused by the lack of an urlpattern with the name 'edit_Profile'.